# regex to match the pattern in python3 using match method

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I want to know the regex using re.match method to match below pattern.

```
some action 1.1.1.1 on sub.domain.com
```

Currently I'm using below code, which works fine but I want to strip of everything except `sub.domain.com` because using below code I'm getting something like `<http:\\/\\/sub.domain.com|sub.domain.com>`

```
some\s+action+\s+(.*)\s+on\s+(.*)
```

Comment: Please show the exact code that you're using, not just the regex part of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you would use a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Notice you have two capturing groups in your question, but you only want one. Here would be an example of one where you get the captured group after the first four "words" (defined as one or more non-spaces plus a space):

- [`(?:\S+\s){4}(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/CHmcQy/1)

[image]

Also note that in actual practice this wouldn't work too well -- what if "some action" is ten words? Instead you might want to do something more targeted such as a regex to match (in pseudocode) `<IP> on (<domain>)`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s='some action 1.1.1.1 on sub.domain.com'
>>> re.match(r'(?:\S+\s){4}(.*)', s).group(1) # not using anchors, not sure if you need that?
# 'sub.domain.com'
```